# git pull into a specific directory

Tags: git, repository, clone, push, pull

My situation is the following:

I have a git Repo A which contains a folder referencing material from another 'project' stored in git Repo B. The folder is really just a symbolic link so it doesn't actually exist.

What I would like to do is 'git pull' from Repo B into this folder ONLY and then push back into Repo A preserving as much of the history as possible (incase changes need to go the other way).

I could just manually upload all the files but that would loose all the history. Also I could just have 2 separate repos and a link but I would like to try and merge project B into project A if possible.

Does git have something along the lines of....

```
git remote add projectb GITURLFORB
mkdir projectb
git add projectb && git commit projectb
git push origin master
git pull projectb master --into_folder projectb
git push origin master
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use `submodules` to include `projectB`. See http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html

The biggest advantage of submodules is that `projectA` will point to a particular commit in `projectB` even if new commits have been made in `projectB`. This allows `projectB` to evolve without worrying about breaking `projectA`. If the new commits in `projectB` will work with `projectA`, you can update the pointer in `projectA`.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, that does seem to be what I wanted!

Project A would then always reference a particular part of Project B and they can evolve independently and 're-merge' at a later point in time.

Excellent thankyou